# set current location as the center of the map - MapBox React Native

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Im trying to set the camera view on the current location marker where the camera will rotate around the current location

when the current location is on the center of the map i got this effect. but i want the map to rotate around the current location even though the current location not on the center of the map

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `followUserMode="course"`

```
<MapboxGL.Camera
    followUserLocation={true}
    followUserMode="course"     
/>
```